# Is it Possible to Assign an Alias to a Function?

Tags: vba, excel, function, alias

I am writing a simple function, such as:

```
Function myFunction() As Variant
    'Some rules
End Function
```

For the above function, is it possible to assign an *Alias* like you can do with API calls?

Obviously this isn't the proper syntax, but you get the idea:

```
Function myFunction() Alias myFunc As Variant
    'Some rules
End Function
```

This would allow me to use either name:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print myFunction
    Debug.Print myFunc
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe this has been asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312447/define-a-function-alias-in-vba-possible).

Comment: @TheNotSoGuru, I added an completely new answer based on so called *`SoundEx` search* as you slightly modified your *initial question (cf. comment as of 1/22)* and in order to allow a clear view over an independant and maybe innovative approach to get function names.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*<del>I don't understand why you would need to have a VBA alias for an VBA function.</del>*

API Aliases are for referring to a function or other object in a DLL,
if it's "given name" can't be used in the module that requires it.

> Alias —— Indicates that the procedure being called has another
> name in the DLL. This is useful when the external procedure name is
> the same as a keyword. You can also use Alias when a DLL procedure has
> the same name as a public variable, constant, or any other procedure in
> the same scope. Alias is also useful if any characters in the DLL
> procedure name aren't allowed by the DLL naming convention. <sup>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declare-statement))</sup>

...but to answer your question, *sure* you could create alternate name for a function, with only a slight modification to your code:

---

> <sub>Your Function:</sub>
>
> ```
> Function myFunction() As Variant
>     'Some rules
> End Function
> ```

---

> <sub>Assign an alternate name:</sub>
>
> ```
> Function myFunc() As Variant
>    myFunc = myFunction
> End Function
> ```

---

> <sub>This would allow you to use either name:</sub>
>
> ```
> Sub Test()
>     Debug.Print myFunction
>     Debug.Print myFunc
> End Sub
> ```

---

## EDIT:  *"Can't remember UDF Names"*

<sub>(When I said I didn't understand why you needed to do this, I assumed you didn't have a memory like mine!  *Now* I understand your reasoning, giving multiple names to the *same* function!)</sub>

*What,* haven't you memorized the name and syntax of all your custom VBA functions yet, on top of the 1000's of built-in functions, procedures and objects, and the seemingly *unlimited list* of property, method, and class names??

*Me neither.*

A feature that helps trigger my memory when coding in VBA is the
***List of Properties/Methods***.

**Start typing the name of a function** or procedure and hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>**, and **you'll get a list** of custom *and* built-in functions, methods, procedures, etc.**

[image: Ctrl+J exanmple]

I noticed that your sample function names all started with "`my`".  That may have been just for illustrative purposes, however, a specific naming convention like that would also help by grouping your functions together in the Properties/Methods Dialog Box.

- See also: **List of the 100+ [VBA Keyboard Shortcuts](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/shortcut-keys.htm)** <sub>*(in case you forget the key combination!)*</sub>

---

## More ways to remember *How things work* and *what they're called*:

You can also **add a description** to a UDF (User-Defined Function), which would appear when entering the function name on a worksheet:

[image: UDF Descr screenshot]

See: **[How to put a 'Tooltip' on a user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262521/8112776)**

---

### Related:

- [Add a Description to a User Defined Function in Excel](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/DesciptionToUDF.htm) (without VBA)
- [VBA Productivity Tip: Procedure List](https://excelvirtuoso.net/2017/04/23/vba-productivity-tip-procedure-list/#Finding_Built-In_Subroutines)
- [The Quest for the Excel Custom Function Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517538/8112776) (C#)

---

Taking it a step further than the description, **Registering the User-Defined Function** allows not only the creation of a description for the *function*, but also detailed information about each of the **function's parameters** and their data types; you can even specify ***Shortcut Key(s)***, add links to custom "***Help***" files/pages, and even assign a ***Category*** for the UDF.

These extended attributes display in the **`Insert Function`** dialog , accessible by clicking the [image: 'FX' button to the left of the formula bar] button to the left of the formula bar, or by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>:

[image: Insert Function dialog]

Excel doesn't have a built-in interface for editing parameter descriptions so VBA is required. Relevant documentation can be hard to locate.

---

### Code & Info about Registering User-Defined Functions

- JKP: [Registering a User Defined Function with Excel](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/RegisterUDF00.asp)
- MSDN: [Application.MacroOptions Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-macrooptions-method-excel)
- [Add Description To A Custom VBA Function](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/07/add-description-to-custom-vba-function.html)

---

## Create a ribbon button to list VBA Procedures

I haven't tried this but I can see how it could be very handy, especially since it would be easy to customize further, perhaps with project-specific function lists and other information.

A button can be added to the ribbon, that when clicked displays a list of VBA procedures/functions, using XML and VBA to display a user form from a button. There's also an option to **save** the list of procedures to a text file.

[image: Image from: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC297331.jpg]

You can already see the procedures in a workbook from the Macros button on the Developers tab. However, only parameter-less subroutines in modules and within a worksheet are displayed in the Macros dialog box. Functions and subroutines with parameters do not show up. The code described in this column displays all of the subroutines and functions in the workbook.

More information and complete code is available **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd890502(v=office.12).aspx)**.

---

## VBA Code that writes VBA Code!?

By programmatically manipulating the VBA Editor (VBE), you can write code in VBA that reads or modifies other VBA projects, modules and procedures, and could be used to automate development-related tasks.  This is called **[extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility)** because it extends the *editor* -- you can use VBA code to create new VBA code.  You can use these features to write custom procedures that create, change, or delete VBA modules and code procedures.

The amazing [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/topic.aspx) has done it again, with detailed instructions and complete code available **here** for some of the fun things extensibility can do for you.

A partial list of code on Chip's page (which is [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)):

- Add/Delete/Rename a Module in a Project
- Add/Delete/Rename a Procedure in a Module
- Copy Modules Between Projects
- Create a New Procedure in a Code Module
- Create an Event Procedure
- Listing all Procedures in a Module
- Read a Procedure Declaration
- Search a Module For Text
- Fix Screen Flicker in the VBE
- Export a VBComponent to a Text File
- Test if a VBComponent Exists
- Determine the Workbook Associated with a VBProject
- Count lines of code in Module/Project/Component

The methods use the ***VBA Extensibility*** [library] (http://www.exceltoolset.com/setting-a-reference-to-the-vba-extensibility-library-by-code/) (reference) and require programmatic access to the VBA Project, which is a security setting in Excel's options.  See Chip's page for more info.

Chip's pages also have great information and code available on [Customizing Menus with VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbemenus.aspx), which could have benefit in making the developer's *own* job easier.

---

A seemingly "forgotten" ability of VBA if functionality to ***control* and even *intercept* built-in commands**.  This could also be used to benefit the developer (especially one with a poor memory!)...  More information and examples from Microsoft **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627337(v=office.12).aspx)**.

---

Comment: good answer - with possible disadvantage of many functions instead of one where I know where I have to look at (let aside a class approach). So it think it's up to the user.

Comment: I think this is probably as close as I will get to what I am wanting. In a project where I may create many functions I may not remember if I named a function `verifyRange` vs `verifyRng`. If it comes down to it I suppose I can create a module just for aliases.

Comment: *Ah I see now* - the ***memory*** issue - that makes more sense.  When I said I didn't understand why you needed to do this, I assumed you didn't have a memory like mine!  This I can totally relate to.  Generally my solution is whiteboards all over my work area.  :-)

Comment: I just remembered a keyboard shortcut that just might become your favorite.  I will edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @TheNotSoGuru Why not use a consistent naming convention? This alias-based approach is likely to be a debugging headache sooner or later.

Comment: @ashleedawg I really appreciate the extended answer! Thanks for that! Glad I was able to clear some things up too :D

Comment: @TheNotSoGuru As John Coleman notes, the solution to your memory issue is just maintaining a consistent naming convention. All functions should have descriptive names, and they should be verbs (such as verify, get, pull, etc.). I find 'Get' to be the most useful for functions that return something. I also highly recommend names that don't use abbreviations (So VerifyRange over VerifyRng), but this is personal preference. Consistent names will go much father than aliasing.

Comment: This over-the-top awesome examplary answer will be earning a bounty as soon as the question is eligible for one. Keep them coming!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Not sure if you still wanted to give ashleedawg her bounty xD

Comment: Another useful memory aid is to put related functions together in different modules and rename your modules - I nearly always have a module named G for global variables, one named DB for database connections and functions, one Util for utility functions. Then type the name of the module followed by dot, and all the public functions in that module are listed automatically, just like a class module.

Comment: @QHarr — *ain't it handy?!*  It's [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/).   If *"a picture says 1000 words"*, then how many words does an animated GIF say, when trying to explain something technical?   ...plus I keep finding new uses for it outside of here; so much that I felt obligated to donate to the developer...

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks. I had been told and forgot. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @QHarr — np, least I can do for the *["13th place Excel/VBA Question Answer'er of the Year"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/800909/top-vba-excel-answerers-this-year#resultSets)* [out of 1662...] ...not that it's a competition!  ☺

Comment: What???? And there I was worrying cos so busy at work I haven’t been able to answer questions. Then was scanning through your answers to learn some new stuff as was worried I was falling behind the curve!

Comment: No way, I'm trying to catch up to you.  Maybe you *should* focus on your work more... ☺

Comment: I think you will probably overtake me quite soon at this rate. <Grabs hankie and wipes eye.. Damn onions.....> #Notpayingattentiontoyourscore

Comment: @QHarr — Don't sweat it, we're pretty much *"neck-and-neck"* anyhow, and besides, I suspect I have more free time on my hands than you do.  *...and [here's proof of **both** those theories](http://jmp.sh/ovQ28Ef)!* (*and of course, the* [Source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/801361/#resultSets)) ...haha

Comment: This basically says you are kicking my a*! :-) And people like to look at you more :-(

Comment: No, this says I just wasted an hour and need to get a life!

Comment: Lol. I forgot you could query SO. I suspect that will be some of my life gone shortly. I only started answering questions in September and I enjoy it but as you can see, when work gets busy, I switch to asking questions....

Comment: You & I combined answered 3 questions prior to September, and **470** since September (with a 50½/49½% split).  I call that pretty damn close (and I figure the community's the *real* winner in this game!)

Answer (score 1):

**Simple VBA example (no classes)**

As you are calling yourself *TheNotSoGuru*, try the following relative simple approach: Instead of an *API* like `alias` definition you would have to write your alias definitions in ONE user defined **alias() function**.

**Calling test procedure**

This shows you how to call your aliases using **ONE** user defined `alias` function; the first argument is your alias Name as string, other arguments define possible arguments of the original functions themselves:

```
Option Explicit     ' declaration head of your code module

Sub Test()
Debug.Print "0) Original Function", myFunction
Debug.Print "1) alias(""(myFunc1"")", alias("myFunc1")
Debug.Print "2) alias(""(myFunc2"")", alias("myFunc2")      ' too less arguments
Debug.Print "2) alias(""(myFunc2"",false)", alias("myFunc2", False)
End Sub
```

**Example functions**

The *first example* needs **no argument**; the *second example* demonstrates an incorrect as well as a correct alias function call - the original function attends the input of a boolean argument (`True` or `False`).

```
Function myFunction() As Variant
'Some rules
'...
'return result
 myFunction = "Result from myFunction"
End Function

Function myFunctionWithOneArgument(Optional ByVal b As Boolean = True) As String
'Some rules
If b Then
   myFunctionWithOneArgument = "result from myFunctionWithOneArgument " & "okay"
Else
   myFunctionWithOneArgument = "result from myFunctionWithOneArgument " & "without comment"
End If
End Function
```

> ===============
>   **Example of an Alias() function**

You are responsible to insert your alias definitions into the alias function. 
It allows you even to force inputs of the correct number of arguments by raising a 450 error "Wrong number of arguments ..." via error handling. If an error occurs a messagebox displays an error message.

```
Function alias(ByVal sFunc, Optional arg1, Optional arg2, Optional arg3)
On Error GoTo oops           ' error handler
Select Case sFunc & ""       ' check your own aliases as string values 
  Case "myFunc1", "1"        ' your alias Definition(s)
       alias = myFunction    ' return original function myFunction
  Case "myFunc2", "One"      ' see above
       ' defines if one argument is needed here:
       If IsMissing(arg1) Then Err.Raise (450)   ' too less arguments if arg1 is missing
       alias = myFunctionWithOneArgument(arg1)
  Case Else
       alias = "Unknown function alias " & sFunc
End Select
EverythingOkay:     Exit Function

oops:
MsgBox "Function: " & sFunc & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
       "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
       Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error - Wrong number of arguments"
Err.Clear
End Function
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. The issue is not that I necessarily want to call out the alias intentionally, it's an issue of forgetting what I many have named a function to begin with (ie. `verifyRange` vs `verifyRng`). If I knew I was calling the alias name to begin with then I wouldn't need to call the alias. But your solution does work and it was very well thought out. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Searching Aliases via Similarity**

**A) Intro**

> **Your Comment as of 1/22:** "The issue is not that I necessarily want to call out the alias intentionally, it's an issue of forgetting what I may have named a function to begin with (ie. `verifyRange` vs `verifyRng`). If I knew I was calling the alias name to begin with then I wouldn't need to call the alias. But your solution does work and it was very well thought out."

Due to your example in above cited comment: As you **slightly modified your initial question**, I thought about an alternative solution and added it as an independant **new answer**:

> ► You could take some advantage of using a so called **`SoundEx` search** to group *procedure names* based on a **phonetic algorithm**.

**Method:** A **Soundex code** identifies a set of similar sounding terms, names or ... ► *procedure names*. If you combine this with a loop through a **VBIDE** list of all existing procedures/functions (*don't forget to set a reference*) you are able to get the most likely alias(es) listed.

> **Example result**

```
1/1 Project(s): "VBAProject" (D:\Excel\test.xlsm)
**Project name: "VBAProject" ** (Host Project)
++SoundEx("verifyRange")="V616"
--   Found --  Procedure/Function name(s) ---------  ------------------
[Prc: Sub]     verifyRng   in Std Module modTest1    Line#: 2/[Body: 3]
[Prc: Sub]     verifyRange in Std Module modSortDict Line#: 6/[Body: 6]
```

**Note:** This method builds a **condensed alphanumeric code** based on the **six phonetic classifications** of *human speech sounds (bilabial, labiodental, dental, alveolar, velar, and glottal)*, removing vocals and some occurences of 'H','W' and 'Y'; the code consists of the first capitalized letter and three following digits (filled with `0` if no more consonants found) . BTW origins date back to the late 1800's used for *indexing American census records*.

**Links**

[Find the word which I closest to the particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237795/find-the-word-which-i-closest-to-the-particular-string/19239560#19239560)
http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/SoundEx1/SoundEx1.htm#JavaScriptCode
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

**Soundex Example**

To demonstrate the soundex coding, try the following example call with identical results:

```
Sub testSoundEx()
Dim i As Integer
Dim a()
a = Array("verifyRange", "verifyRng", "vrfRanges")
Debug.Print "Proc name", "SoundEx Code": Debug.Print String(50, "-")
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    Debug.Print a(i), SoundEx(a(i))
Next i
End Sub
```

**SoundEx Function**

```
Function SoundEx(ByVal s As String) As String
' Site:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237795/find-the-word-which-i-closest-to-the-particular-string/19239560#19239560
' Source: Developed by Richard J. Yanco
' Method: follows the Soundex rules given at http://home.utah-inter.net/kinsearch/Soundex.html
Dim Result As String, c As String * 1
Dim Location As Integer
s = UCase(s)                ' use upper case
' First character must be a letter
If Len(Trim(s)) = 0 Then
   Exit Function
ElseIf Asc(Left(s, 1)) < 65 Or Asc(Left(s, 1)) > 90 Then
    SoundEx = ""
    Exit Function
Else
  ' (1) Convert to Soundex: letters to their appropriate digit,
    '             A,E,I,O,U,Y ("slash letters") to slashes
    '             H,W, and everything else to zero-length string
    Result = Left(s, 1)
    For Location = 2 To Len(s)
        Result = Result & Category(Mid(s, Location, 1))
    Next Location
  ' (2) Remove double letters
    Location = 2
    Do While Location < Len(Result)
        If Mid(Result, Location, 1) = Mid(Result, Location + 1, 1) Then
            Result = Left(Result, Location) & Mid(Result, Location + 2)
        Else
            Location = Location + 1
        End If
    Loop
   ' (3) If category of 1st letter equals 2nd character, remove 2nd character
    If Category(Left(Result, 1)) = Mid(Result, 2, 1) Then
        Result = Left(Result, 1) & Mid(Result, 3)
    End If
   ' (4) Remove slashes
    For Location = 2 To Len(Result)
        If Mid(Result, Location, 1) = "/" Then
            Result = Left(Result, Location - 1) & Mid(Result, Location + 1)
        End If
    Next
   ' (5) Trim or pad with zeroes as necessary
    Select Case Len(Result)
        Case 4
            SoundEx = Result
        Case Is < 4
            SoundEx = Result & String(4 - Len(Result), "0")
        Case Is > 4
            SoundEx = Left(Result, 4)
    End Select
End If
End Function
```

**Helper function called by SoundEx()**

*This helper function returns a letter code based on phonetic classifications (see notes above):*

```
Private Function Category(c) As String
'   Returns a Soundex code for a letter
Select Case True
    Case c Like "[AEIOUY]"
        Category = "/"
    Case c Like "[BPFV]"
        Category = "1"
    Case c Like "[CSKGJQXZ]"
        Category = "2"
    Case c Like "[DT]"
        Category = "3"
    Case c = "L"
        Category = "4"
    Case c Like "[MN]"
        Category = "5"
    Case c = "R"
        Category = "6"
    Case Else 'This includes H and W, spaces, punctuation, etc.
        Category = ""
End Select
End Function
```

> **► Solution to your issue - Example Call to get Functions by Alias**

**B) Memory issue or how to jog one's memory**

You can use the following example call to search for procedure/function aliases via Syntax `listProc {function name string}`, e.g. `listProc "verifyRange"` and you get a condensed **list of all found aliases** in the **Immediate Window** of your Visual Basic Editor (VBE):

```
Sub Test()
listProc "verifyRange"  ' possibly gets verifyRange AND verifyRng via SoundEx "V616"
'listProc "verify"      ' possibly gets nothing, as SoundEx "V610" has no fourth consonant
'listProc                '[ displays ALL procedures without SoundEx Filter ]
End Sub
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that the SoundEx Code (e.g. "V616" for `verifyRange`) is limited to a length of four alphanumeric characters.
If you are looking for "verify" only (= 3 consonants V+r+f), you would get "V610" instead without findings of "verifyRange" or "verifyRng" (V+r+f+r).
In this case you should search for a pair of variants.

=============================
**Main procedure `listProc`** =====================

```
Sub listProc(Optional ByVal sFuncName As String)
' Purpose: display procedures using a SoundEx Filter
' Call:   0 arguments or empty argument - ALL procedures without filter
'         1 argument (not empty)        - procedures found via SoundEx
' Note:   requires reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
' Declare variables to access the macros in the workbook.
Dim VBAEditor      As VBIDE.VBE         ' VBE
Dim objProject     As VBIDE.VBProject   ' Projekt
Dim objComponent   As VBIDE.VBComponent ' Modul
Dim objCode        As VBIDE.CodeModule  ' Codeblock des Moduls
' Declare other miscellaneous variables.
Dim sProcName      As String
Dim sndx As String, sndx2 As String
Dim pk             As vbext_ProcKind       ' proc kind (Sub, Function, Get, Let)
Dim strPK          As String, sTyp As String
Dim iLine          As Integer, iBodyLine As Integer, iStartLine As Integer
Dim i              As Integer
Dim bShow          As Boolean             ' show procedure name
Dim bSoundEx       As Boolean
If Len(Trim(sFuncName)) > 0 Then bSoundEx = True  ' show alle procedures!
' ========================================
' Get the project details in the workbook.
' ========================================
  Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE

  Set objProject = VBAEditor.ActiveVBProject
' Set objProject = VBAEditor.VBProjects("MyProcject")   ' 1-based, project name or item number

 For i = 1 To VBAEditor.VBProjects.Count    ' show name, filename, buildfilename (DLL)
     Debug.Print i & "/" & _
                 VBAEditor.VBProjects.Count & " Project(s): """ & _
                 VBAEditor.VBProjects(i).Name & """ (" & VBAEditor.VBProjects(i).filename & ")"
 Next i
' get SoundEx of Function name
  sndx2 = SoundEx(sFuncName)
' ==================
' ? PROJECT NAME
' ==================
'   objProject.Type ...vbext_pt_HostProject 100 Host-Project
'                   ...vbext_pt_StandAlone  101 Standalone-Project
  Debug.Print "**Project name: """ & objProject.Name & """ ** (" & _
              IIf(objProject.Type = 100, "Host Project", "Standalone") & ")"
  If bSoundEx Then Debug.Print "++SoundEx(""" & sFuncName & """)=""" & sndx2 & """" & _
                               vbNewLine & "--   Found --  Procedure/Function name(s)"

' Iterate through each component (= Module) in the project.
For Each objComponent In objProject.VBComponents        ' alle MODULE
    ' Find the code module for the project (Codeblock in current component/=module).
      Set objCode = objComponent.CodeModule
      ' =============
      ' ? MODULE NAME
      ' =============
      If objCode.CountOfLines > 0 And Not bSoundEx Then
         Debug.Print " *** " & _
             sModType(objComponent.Type) & " ** " & objComponent.Name & " ** "
      End If
  ' Scan through the code module, looking for procedures.
  ' Durch alle Codezeilen des jeweiligen Moduls gehen
    iLine = 1
    Do While iLine < objCode.CountOfLines               ' alle Zeilen durchackern (1/End ...)

      ' =================
      ' Get Procedurename                               ' !! SETZT AUTOMATISCH >> pk << !!
      ' =================
        sProcName = objCode.ProcOfLine(iLine, pk)       ' jede nächste Zeile auf Prozedurbeginn checken

        If sProcName <> "" Then                         ' ohne Declaration head
            ' -----------------
            ' Found a procedure
            ' -----------------
            ' a) Get its details, and ...
              strPK = pk                                 ' 0-Prc|1-Let/2-Set/3-Get Werte abfangen !!!
           '' iStartLine = objCode.ProcStartLine(sProcName, strPK)  ' here = iLine !!
              iBodyLine = objCode.ProcBodyLine(sProcName, strPK)    ' Zeilennr mit Sub/Function/L/S/Get
              sTyp = sPrcType(objCode.Lines(iBodyLine, 1))          ' Sub|Fct|Prp
            ' b) Check Soundex
              If bSoundEx Then
                 sndx = SoundEx(sProcName)
                 If sndx = sndx2 Or UCase(sProcName) = UCase(sFuncName) Then
                    bShow = True
                 Else
                    bShow = False
                 End If
              Else
                 bShow = True
              End If
              ' ==============
              ' c) ? PROC NAME
              ' --------------
              If bShow Then
                 Debug.Print "    " & "[" & sPK(strPK) & ": " & sTyp & "] " & _
                          sProcName & IIf(bSoundEx, " in " & sModType(objComponent.Type) & " " & objComponent.Name, "") & vbTab, _
                          "Line#: " & iLine & "/[Body: " & iBodyLine & "]"
              End If
            ' -------------------------------------------
            ' d) Skip to the end of the procedure !
            '    => Add line count to current line number
            ' -------------------------------------------
              iLine = iLine + objCode.ProcCountLines(sProcName, pk)
        Else
            ' This line has no procedure, so => go to the next line.
            iLine = iLine + 1
        End If
    Loop

Next objComponent

' Clean up and exit.
  Set objCode = Nothing
  Set objComponent = Nothing
  Set objProject = Nothing


End Sub
```

**3 Helper Functions to the Main procedure `listProc`**

*These helper functions return additional information to procedures and module:*

```
Function sPK(ByVal prockind As Long) As String
' Purpose: returns short description of procedure kind (cf ProcOfLine arguments)
Dim a(): a = Array("Prc", "Let", "Set", "Get")
sPK = a(prockind)
End Function

Function sPrcType(ByVal sLine As String) As String
' Purpose: returns procedure type abbreviation
If InStr(sLine, "Sub ") > 0 Then
   sPrcType = "Sub"     ' sub
ElseIf InStr(sLine, "Function ") > 0 Then
   sPrcType = "Fct"     ' function
Else
    sPrcType = "Prp"    ' property (Let/Set/Get)
End If
End Function

Function sModType(ByVal moduletype As Integer) As String
' Purpose: returns abbreviated module type description
Select Case moduletype
   Case 100
     sModType = "Tab Module"
   Case 1
     sModType = "Std Module"
   Case 2
     sModType = "CLS Module"
   Case 3
     sModType = "Frm Module"
   Case Else
     sModType = "?"
 End Select
End Function
```